# Add event to all buttons of the same class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, mvc-editor-templates

This might be easy but I've searched SO and tried some suggestions for this none of which work. I'm using an MVC Editor Template that has a div with a standard html button and other fields. When I pass a collection to the template it will render the fields of each item in the collection with unique ids. Then I want to open a dialog box when any of the buttons are clicked. The buttons are rendered as such within the Editor Template:

```
@model ProductViewModel
<span>
    <button id="btnSelectTags-@(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix)" class="sig-button ie-shadowed select-tag" type="button" title="Select tags..." style="margin-right: 10px">Select tags</button>
</span>
// other fields
```

So if I pass a collection with 2 objects to the Editor Template I get the html below:

```
<button title="Select tags..." class="sig-button ie-shadowed select-tag" id="btnSelectTags-Products[0]" style="margin-right: 10px;" type="button">
// other fields then next item:
<button title="Select tags..." class="sig-button ie-shadowed select-tag" id="btnSelectTags-Products[1]" style="margin-right: 10px;" type="button">
```

This seems fine and gives each button a unique id. They need to have a unique id (I think) as the item in every div can have its own set of tags. So I want to add a click event to each button that will open a dialog box, using this jQuery (I've tried including the other classes in the selector also and tried without "button"):

```
if ($("button.select-tag")) {
    $(".select-tag").click(function () {
        showTagDialogBox();
    });
}
```

Here's the div where the tags get rendered:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <div id="tagDialogBox" title="Add Tags">
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ProductViewModels)
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the showTagDialogBox function:

```
function showTagDialogBox() {
    $('#tagDialogBox').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: "Select Tags",
        modal: true,
        height: 530,
        width: 700,
        buttons: {
            "Save": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

However when I click any of the buttons nothing happens - I don't get any js errors in Firebug either. Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong? Here's a pic of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it - I had

> autoOpen: false

whereas it should have been set to true.

* *slaps forehead* *

Answer (score 3):

Two things to watch out for that may explain what's going on here:

The following will always evaluate to true, even when no buttons exist in the DOM:

```
if ($("button.select-tag")) { }
```

Instead, use:

```
if ($("button.select-tag").size() > 0) { }
```

Secondly, depending on whether your buttons exist within a form element, the page may be posting data back to the server before the dialog has a chance to appear. To prevent this, use `.preventDefault()` within your click event handler as follows:

```
$(".select-tag").click(function (e) {
    showTagDialogBox();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it even without checking the element because if the element doesn't exist on the page it won't be a problem, so you can do it like

```
$(".select-tag").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showTagDialogBox();
});
```

but if you want to check it first then you can try this

```
if ($("button.select-tag").length) {
    $(".select-tag").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        showTagDialogBox();
    });
}
```

or (if you are using latest version of jquery)

```
$(".select-tag").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    showTagDialogBox();
});
```

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions but neither of them work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Just a generic answer to your title, i.e. to add click event to all buttons of some class:

```
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Items that NEED to be set after the page is loaded.
            $('.some-class').on('click', 'button', function (event) 
            {
               event.preventDefault();
               someFunction();
            }
            // And so on.
        });

        //Items that DON'T NEED to be called on page load can be put outside document.ready. For eg:
        function someFunction() { // Some logic }
    </script>
}
```